# Redirect from the dashboard to edit.php if wp_is_mobile() is true

Tags: admin, wp-admin, redirect, wp-redirect

Looking for a way to redirect the user from the dashboard straight to `edit.php` if `wp_is_mobile()` is true.

This is what I've tried:

```
function redirect_if_mobile() {
    $screen = get_current_screen();
    if($screen->base == 'dashboard') {
        if ( wp_is_mobile() ) {
            $url = admin_url( 'edit.php' );
            wp_redirect( $url );
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'redirect_if_mobile');
```

The problem is that `get_current_screen()` isn't defined in either `admin_init` or `admin_menu` (if you hook onto `admin_head` instead it's too late and headers have already been sent).

Ideas?

Comment: You could use `global $pagenow; if('index.php'==$pagenow)/* etc */`. Also, [Adminimize](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/adminimize/) has the option to hide the Dashboard menu item and redirect to other page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The action you're looking for is auth_redirect, which is before the headers but still recognizes $pagenow to tell which page you're on:

```
add_action('auth_redirect', 'the_mobile_boot');
function the_mobile_boot() {
    global $pagenow;

    if ( $pagenow == 'index.php' && wp_is_mobile() ) {
        header( 'Location: ' . get_admin_url(null, 'edit.php') );
        exit;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can actually use the function you're using, you just need to use `load-index.php` *(no need for globals if you don't need them):*

```
add_action('load-index.php', function(){
    if(get_current_screen()->base == 'dashboard' && !wp_is_mobile())
        wp_redirect(admin_url('edit.php'));
});
```

Comment: Dude! I just upvoted and have no idea if this works, but looks fantastic. https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/load-(page). Do you know what is available here ( meaning "plugins_loaded, init" actions )?

Answer (score 0):

Alright, found one solution, although not that elegant.

```
function load_if_mobile() {
    if ( wp_is_mobile() ) {?>
    <script>
        window.location = '/wp-admin/edit.php';
    </script><?php
    }
}
add_action('admin_head-index.php', 'load_if_mobile');
```

Comment: And here, your original `wp_redirect()` works, ain't it?